# Which event is triggered by deleting a character with the x key?

Tags: vimscript, autocmd, microsoft-windows

I have written a vimscript function. I want to use `autocmd` to call this function when a character is deleted with the `x` key. But autocmd requires an event name. Which event is triggered when a character is deleted with the `x` key?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such event.

There is TextChanged event that is generally called when text was changed in normal mode (including `x` I guess). I am not sure this what you need though...

Why not remap `x` key to delete a character and call your function?

```
func! MyFunc()
    echo printf("You have just deleted '%s'", getreg(v:register))
endfunc
noremap x x:call MyFunc()<CR>
```

Comment: Thank you. Remapping x works exactly as expected!